# How to report jasmine test results/output into a text file using karma

Tags: node.js, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I want to show only "dots" report in command prompt and complete "progress" report saved in a text file. Is there any way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an existing module for human readable text file outputs, hopefully someone can recommend one. If you want something human readable you could write your own reporter following the patterns in [jasmine-reporters](https://github.com/larrymyers/jasmine-reporters/tree/master/src).

I do generate a junit format xml file for use with jenkins alongside my dots, here is a snippet from `config.set({ ... })` in my karma.conf showing how to output to two reporters:

```
plugins : [
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-junit-reporter'
        ],

reporters: ['progress','junit'],

junitReporter : {
  outputFile: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'junit-unit-frontend.xml'),
  suite: ''
},
```